# long click event in D3

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, click

Is it possible to implement a long (prolongued) click event on an element in d3?
I suppose the following code is not allowed:

```
d3.selectAll("#mybutton").on("longClick",longClickFunction);
```

**Edit.**
I need a long click to achieve something like a slider.
Suppose that there is a DOM element whose html text is 1. With a click on `#mybutton` I want to increase it by one. With a long click on `#mybutton` I want to increase it by one more more quickly until I release the mouse button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no longClick event in d3.js, but you can toy with the mousedown and mouse up events to calculate the length of time between the two. This in effect allows you to measure click duration.

The snippet below has a threshold for click length defined in the data, so each rect element will have a different threshold to trigger the 'long click' event (half second and full second respectively):

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',200);

var data = [{color:'orange', duration: 500} ,{color: 'steelblue', duration: 1000} ];

var startTime;
var endTime;

svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('x',function(d,i) { return 20 + i * 40; })
   .attr('y',50)
   .attr('height',30)
   .attr('width',30)
   .attr('fill',function(d) { return d.color; })
   .on('mousedown', function() { startTime = new Date(); })
   .on('mouseup',function(d) { 
       endTime = new Date(); 
       if ((endTime - startTime) > d.duration) { 
           console.log("long click, " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds long");
       }
       else {
           console.log("regular click, " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds long");
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

## Edit

If however, you want to trigger events *during* (and not after) the long click, such as incrementing, a similar approach can be taken using the mousedown and mouseup listeners to record the length of the 'click':

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',200);

var data = [{color:'orange'} ,{color: 'steelblue'}];

var clicked;
var i;

svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('x',function(d,i) { return 20 + i * 40; })
   .attr('y',20)
   .attr('height',30)
   .attr('width',30)
   .attr('fill',function(d) { return d.color; })
   .on('mousedown', function() { i=1; clicked = true; click(); })
   .on('mouseup',function() { clicked = false; })
   .on('mouseout',function() { clicked = false; });
  
function click() {
  if (clicked) {
    startTime = new Date();
    console.log("increment is: " + i);

    if (i < 6) { 
      setTimeout(function() { 
          click(++i) 
      }, 350);  // start slow
    }
    else if (i < 15) {
      setTimeout(function() { 
          click(++i) 
      }, 150);  // speed up
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(function() { 
          click(++i) 
      }, 25);  // go fast
    }
    
    
  }
  
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

For this snippet, I've added a mouseout listener to account for mice drifting while clicked - otherwise mouseup won't trigger.

Comment: According to your code a long click is recognized only when the mouse button is released. I update my question to be clearer.

Comment: I've updated with an additional snippet that should be more applicable.